# Why does fork() flag each page in both processes as read-only?

Tags: c, process, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I was reading a textbook which talks about how `fork()` works with virtual memory:

> When the `fork` function is called by the current process, the kernel creates various data structures for the new process and assigns it a unique PID. To create the virtual memory for the new process, it creates exact copies of the current process’s `mm_struct`, area structs, and page tables. It flags each page in **both processes as read-only** [emphasis added], and flags each area struct in both processes as private copy-on-write.

<sup>Source: *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective*, Chapter 3, Section 9.8.2 - The `fork` Function Revisited.</sup>

I don't understand why it needs to flag each page in both processes as read-only. If each page in the parent process is read-only then the parent process will never be able to modify some uninitialised global variables (`.bss` section). How then can the program work?

Comment: Which text-book does the quote come from? Which edition of the book? In which chapter, section and page?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude computer systems a programmer's perspective 3rd Chapter 9 Virtual Memory 9.8.2-The fork Function Revisited Page 872

Comment: Note: `fork` is very often followed by `exec` (by the new process). This is important to remember, in order to see the tricks and optimization of implementations. Note 2: often kernel put pages of process as read-only. So that non-modified pages would not be written back to disk on exit.It is not a "permanent read-only", just an accounting measure ("notify me before data is modified")

Comment: Multiply posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610628/5132 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If each page in the parent process is read-only then the parent process will never be able to modify some uninitialised global variables

That would only be true if the pages stay read only. But they don't as it says in the next part of the sentence:

> and flags each area struct in both processes as private copy-on-write

Each page starts off as read-only so that a single copy can be shared by both parent and child. If either process tries to modify such a page only at that point will a writeable copy be made (if the page is indeed meant to be writeable). After the copy the writing process can make any changes it likes without affecting the other process's original (still read-only) page.

This can save memory for pages that neither parent nor child actually ends up changing.

Answer (score 1):

From [user space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) point of view (that is from [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) used after the [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) in your application code...), the memory pages (managed by the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)) are not all read-only. That abstraction is provided by the kernel.

And after a successful [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) you could call [mprotect(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [munmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html), [sbrk(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) (perhaps used by [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) or [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)...) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) to change the [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and a good textbook on [*Operating Systems*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). See of course [LinuxAteMyRAM](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

From inside the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), things are of course very different. Refer to [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) and [OSDev](https://osdev.org/) websites.

Both the Linux kernel, the [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/), and most applications (e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)) in major Linux distributions such as [Debian](https://debian.org/) are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source). **You are allowed to download and study their source code**.

Consider reading [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), and using [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html). Try `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a terminal.